# Adding required to HTML input when checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, html

I have an hidden div which will contain some HTML inputs which some are needed to be required as part of a form. the div is visible by checking the checkbox and the code looks like this:

```js
$(function() {
  var checkbox = $("#checkbox01");
  var hidden = $("#div01");
  hidden.hide();
  checkbox.change(function() {
    if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
      hidden.show();
    } else {
      hidden.hide();
      $("#username").val("");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><input id="checkbox01" name="checkbox01" type="checkbox">show/hide</label>
<div id="div01">
  <input name="username" type="text" required>
</div>
```

You can see the code in action on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yktnq2aL/)
As you can see the div is hidden when the checkbox is unchecked and also the username is cleaned when the div is hidden (checkbox unchecked).

How can I make the `required` be added to HTML **only if checkbox is checked**, so user won't get prompt to enter value when the div is hidden by Jquery... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `.prop()` to added required attribute to input everytime you show it and remove the attribute everytime you hide it.

```js
$(function() {
  var checkbox = $("#checkbox01");
  var hidden = $("#div01");
  hidden.hide();
  checkbox.change(function() {
    if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
      hidden.show();
      $('#username').prop('required', true); //to add required
    } else {
      hidden.hide();
      $("#username").val("");
      $('#username').prop('required', false); //to remove required
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><input id="checkbox01" name="checkbox01" type="checkbox">show/hide</label>
<div id="div01">
  <input name="username" type="text" required>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just toggle the type to `hidden`, that way it's no longer required

```
$("#checkbox01").on('change', function() {
    $("#div01").toggle(this.checked)
               .find('input').prop('type', this.checked ? 'text' : 'hidden')
               .val('');
    }).trigger('change');
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#checkbox01").on('change', function() {
    $("#div01").toggle(this.checked).find('input').prop('type', this.checked ? 'text' : 'hidden').val('');
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label>
    <input id="checkbox01" name="checkbox01" type="checkbox">show/hide</label>
  <div id="div01">
    <input name="username" type="text" required="required">
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (**JavaScript**)

```js
$(function() {
  var checkbox = $("#checkbox01");
  var hidden = $("#div01");
  hidden.hide();
  checkbox.change(function() {

    if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
      hidden.show();

      document.getElementById("username").required = true;
    } else {
      hidden.hide();
      $("#username").val("");
      document.getElementById("username").required = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input id="checkbox01" name="checkbox01" type="checkbox">show/hide</label>
<div id="div01">
  <input name="username" id="username" type="text">
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#username").prop('required',true);          //to add
$("#username").prop('required',false);         //to remove
```

Answer (score 0):

Add required attribute on check and remove it when unchecked.

```
    $(function() {
      var checkbox = $("#checkbox01");
      var hidden = $("#div01");
      hidden.hide();
      checkbox.change(function() {
        if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
          hidden.show();
          $("#name").attr('required'); //add required attr
        } else {
          hidden.hide();
          $("#username").val("");
          $("#name").removeAttr('required'); // remove required attr
        }
      });
    });
```

Here is your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xj7ps2La/

Answer (score 0):

Update your js to this:

```
    $(function() {
          var checkbox = $("#checkbox01");
          var hidden = $("#div01");
          hidden.hide();
          checkbox.change(function() {
            if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
              checkbox.attr("required",true);
              hidden.show();
            } else {
              hidden.hide();
              checkbox.attr("required",false);
              $("#username").val("");
            }
          });
        });
```